# Explanation of what the sampling distribution of $b_1$ given a normal linear regression model is?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, linear-model

I am reading through my statistics book ([Michael H. Kutner, Christopher J. Nachtsheim, John Neter and William Li (2005) Applied Linear Statistical Models, 5th edition](https://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/rkulik/mat3378/mat3378-textbook.pdf)) and am stuck reading the particular excerpt below

[image]

Specifically the text

> ... repeated sampling when the levels of the predictor variable X are held constant from sample to sample

I guess I understand that $b_1$ could change with different samples from a set of observations. For instance, if we have 100 observations and fit 5 normal linear models to 5 sets $z$, $iid$ samples we would have various values of $b_1$. But where I get lost, is when it stats that the levels of $X$ are held constant.

I guess, I am not even sure how to state my question other than, what does this excerpt mean in other words? Can someone offer another equal explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y varies randomly from sample to sample, but X does not.  Say you have three observations in each sample, and one independent variable X.

In the first sample, X could have values (1, 2, 3)--for example, doses of a drug for three people--and the dependent variable Y could have values (-1, 0, 1)--for example, change in body temperature.

In the second sample, X could have values (1, 2, 3) and Y could have values (-2, 1, 4).

In the third sample, X could have values (1, 2, 3) and Y could have values (0, 2, 3).

And so on.  The X are (by assumption) the same in each sample, while the Y vary from sample to sample, not because X varies, but because something else varies--the individual, the time of day, the staff, all the effects being captured by the error term.